Eigen's inverse() and norm() algorithms appear to return wrong results
Applying Eigen's inverse() method to the MatrixXd
A =
-0.596236      1.00022      1.00042    0.0949589
 1.00022      -3.6074     0.998865     0.114858
 1.00042     0.998865     -5.39316     0.121635
-1.45107e-15  4.72514e-15  6.80733e-15     0.103451

returns
A^-1 =
-7.91935e+15 -2.74325e+15  -1.9771e+15  1.26397e+16
-2.74325e+15 -9.50255e+14 -6.84865e+14  4.37837e+15
 -1.9771e+15 -6.84865e+14 -4.93594e+14  3.15556e+15
144.315      49.9906      36.0291     -220.669

Which obviously isnt the inverse, as
A * A^-1 = 
1.70404    -0.377947    0.0462824     0.545537
1.32584      2.11684     0.325741     -3.34565
-0.446164     0.580614       1.3824    -0.841071
-1.77636e-15 -1.77636e-15 -1.33227e-15            1

isn't even close to the identitity matrix.
I am aware that A is not regular. I find it really counter-intuitive that inverse() returns
random results for a non-invertible matrix rather than throwing an
exception or returning NaN values.
What is even more confusing is that A.norm() returns 6.96425 rather than Inf.
Isn't this a flaw in Eigen?
The regularity of A can be checked by
auto lu = Eigen::FullPivLU<Eigen::MatrixXd>(a);
assert(lu.isInvertible()).

This workaround works for me.
